# Does Hinduism have different types of rebirths?

Tags: philosophy, afterlife, cosmology, samsara

Does Hinduism have a Wheel of Samsara like Buddhism and Jainism, which categorize 6 different options of possible rebirths based on past karma?

Or in Hinduism the only possible rebirths are human or animal?